# TextInputLayout is too High Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Can you guys Help me, I want to use this code

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_cost_of_service"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ic_logo_binar"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/baseline_monetization_on_24"
        app:startIconTint="@color/black">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/tie_cost_of_service"
            android:layout_width="252dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_r"
            android:hint="@string/cost_of_service"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

but it looks like when I want to input some number it apparently too high, and I don't know what is wrong

Comment: Can you please make your question more clear? What do you mean by too high? Are you talking about height of your `EditText`? Can you attach some pictures do better understand? This will help you to get answers quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is becouse of

```
android:layout_height="50dp"
```

It's not enough space for your entered text. There is 2 options:
You can set:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Or you can downsize text size. For example:

```
android:textSize="11sp"
```